# Simple WPF binding question. Binding DataGrid to one structure and array(list) of structures

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to display the contents of a binary file in a few simple DataGrids (xmlns:kit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit").  I know the layout of the file; it's quite simple.

First I have several simple structs of the form:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class PartitionBasicStationData
{
  public uint longitude;
  public uint latitude;
  public uint StationCode;

}
```

I have just one intance of these in the file.  Although it's probably overkill, I'd like to throw it in a Datagrid.  I was hoping I'd automatically get some simple column headers like, "longitude", "latitude", etc. My XAML looks like:

```
<kit:DataGrid Name="m_gridPartion1" MinWidth="120" MinHeight="120"></kit:DataGrid>
```

and in code, after I successfully read the binary file and create a structure, I do this:

```
m_gridPartion1.ItemsSource = new Partition1[1] { partition1 };
//m_gridPartion1.DataContext = new Partition1[1]{partition1}; // also tried this
// m_gridPartion1.ItemsSource = partion1; // and I tried this
```

Should this work?

For my second grid I will also have simple structures, but many of them.  The structure looks like

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class Datum
{
  public uint temperature;
  public uint windVelocity;

}
```

I was hoping I could just do something like this:

```
 m_gridData.ItemsSource = myList;  // myList is List<Datum>
```

Any tutorials or pointers would be much appreciated.  Most of the material I've come across is about binding from XAML (which I'm not opposed to if it's easy) or is overkill (setting column names, etc.).

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your class as

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class PartitionBasicData
{
    public uint longitude { get; set; }
    public uint latitude { get; set; }
    public uint StationCode { get; set; }
}
```

and set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property of the DataGrid to True (if you don't want to define the columns manually)

With these changes, i was able to get the following code to work:

`m_gridPartition1.ItemsSource = new PartitionBasicData[] { new PartitionBasicData() { latitude = 1, longitude = 2, StationCode = 3 }};`

---

**Edit for question asked in comment:**

In this case you will need to remove the `AutoGenerateColumns` attribute and define your columns manually (as you will be specifying a custom column for the `StationCode` property)

For the StationCode column, you will then need to specify a Converter to format your array, or alternatively if the byte[] is always in a known length and format you could just specify the `StringFormat` property of the Binding.

Both methods would require you to either set the `CanUserSort` property on that column to False, or set the `SortMemberPath` property to something that doesn't require converting so that a run-time exception is not thrown when the user clicks the column header. Or since there is only ever one row to this DataGrid as specified in your original question, you could set the `CanUserSortColumns` property on the DataGrid to False.

**Converter method:**

```
<DataGrid Name="m_gridPartition1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Longitude" Binding="{Binding Path=longitude}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Latitude" Binding="{Binding Path=latitude}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Station Code" Binding="{Binding Path=StationCode, Converter={StaticResource someConverterToStyliseByteArray}}" CanUserSort="False" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**StringFormat method:**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Station Code" Binding="{Binding Path=StationCode, StringFormat='{}{0}-{1}-{2}'}" CanUserSort="False" />
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, and marked as answer. Can I ask a bonus question? If I made Station code as  public byte[] StationCode {get; set;}, what would I do so the byte appear in grid?  Currently, it's blank.  I'm guessing that I get int,units,etc. for free, but there's some sort of formatting necessary for byte[].

Comment: Thanks fatty!  I used both ideas (String Format and Converter).  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Expose the fields as public properties and it might work.